# limits at infinity calc1

Tags: calculus

Why is it that when we are finding the limit as x tends to infinity of a function, we disregard all variables on the numerator and denominator, except for the ones with the highest degree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heuristically, it is because terms of higher order degree get bigger way, way faster than terms of lower order degree.

Mathematically, try dividing the numerator and denominator by $n^p$ where $p$ is the largest degree present in the expression. This is just multiplying by 1 and should make what happens in the limit clear.

Answer (score 0):

Because, let for example the numerator be $x^m + x^{m-1}+...+1$ you can write it as $x^m (1+\frac 1 {x} + ... + \frac 1 {x^m}) $. As x tends to $\infty$ the numerator tends to $x^m$ for the theorem of limit product.